# How to put multiple conditions in one regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression for the following scenario.

If line starts with word "**project**", then allow any type of character after it except "." (dot).

*For example:*

> project is to pick up of discontinued items.

The above line should not get selected and the following lines should get selected:

> project :
>   Project #1

I have created regular expression like this, but it is not working in few scenarios. Can anyone help me correcting my regular expression or creating new RE?

```
project\s[\s\S^\.]{0,50}
```

The logic for the above RE is: select string containing word "project", followed by one whitespace character, followed by 0 to 50 characters of all types except dot character.

Comment: The character class matches a space, a not-space, a caret or a dot.  You should probably eliminate most of that and just use '[^.]'.  Inside a character class, dot is not special.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

/^project[^.]*$/i if you want to select "project"

/^project[^.]+$/i if you need at least one char after project

Comment: If an answer works for you, you probably ought to formally accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex,
    ^project\b[:#].*$

The above regex selects the line if it contains project followed by a word boundary (space, tab, comma etc) followed by a : or #. So this will not select "project is to pick up of discontinued items." but it will select "project :"